# How do I get Jackson's LocalDateSerializer to render as an ISO date?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have successfully registered the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule` module with Spring 3.2 and Jackson 2 using the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.mycompany.CustomObjectMapper" />
```

However the result is that the serialisation of `LocalDate` is an array containing the date, i.e. today's date looks like `[2013,3,12]`. How can I get this to return `2013-03-12`?

Comment: It is because of the `LocalDateSerializer` registered by `JodaModule`, you may have to override the serialzer for `LocalDate`

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, was actually hoping not to have to do this thinking that the module would be configurable for specifying formats. I've just had a look at the source for `.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.*` and the other formats seem to look fine, so will just create an implementation of `SimpleModule` that registers these (de)serializers and create my own for `LocalDate`.

Comment: Yes looks like you need to create a module and override

Comment: Actually, I found that because I have `enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);` in my custom config it renders to array, disabling this feature writes as string (which is expected). I had actually overlooked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I had a custom `ObjectMapper` implementation that was setting `enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);`, I had overlooked this, turning this feature off results in what I was expecting.

Unfortunately by default you can't have `DateTime` and `LocalDateTime` serialise as `LocalDateTime` does not have the getter, I was surprised to see that `DateTimeMidnight` will also render as an array and not milliseconds even though the property exists.

As discussed in my comments to the question, it is pretty simple to override this behaviour by creating your own implementation of `JodaModule` (not overriding) and replace the existing plus your overriding implementations. Note however that you must have the same package structure as the original implementation as some classes are package-private (`com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda`).

Comment: You may want to file an RFE for Joda module -- difference may be an oversight, or it might make sense to add more configurability. Module is relatively new and best improvement ideas come from users.